# Converting array of data to strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data in the following format:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "cost": 323,
      "comparison": "High",
      "flag": "Alert"
    }
    ...
]
```

I am trying to prepare this data for *Google charts*, more specifically to make a *Histogram*. The format required is like on next example:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Number'],
    ['Name 1', number1],
    ['Name 2', number2],
    ['Name 3', number3],
    ...
]);
```

So, from my input data, I want to use the `id` and `cost` properties. To approach this, I have implemented next code:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.data[0]).filter(e => !(["comparison","flag"].includes(e)));
const values = this.data.map(e => Object.entries(e).filter(([k]) => keys.includes(k)).map(([, v]) => v));
const formattedArray = [keys, ...values];
```

This somewhat gives me the data I require, I am seeing something like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['id', 'cost'],
    [1, 323]
    ...
]);
```

But my chart is not displaying correctly, and the problem I think I am facing is that I am passing `id's` as an `int`, whereby *Google charts* expects column one to be a `string`.

How can I convert all the values that are placed into column one, so they are strings?

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't get why you use `const keys = Object.keys(this.data[0]).filter(e => !(["comparison","flag"].includes(e)));` to just get an array like `["id", "cost"]`. Why not just declare it like that explicitly? Also, using that approach, and in the case the first object of the array have other `keys` besides `id` and `cost`, those will be included on the `keys` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Number.isInteger()` to check whether the variable is a number, and then use the `toString()` method to convert it. You can use the `index` parameter from the map to only stringify the first column. You could change your code like so:

```js
const data = [{ "id": 1, "cost": 323, "comparison": "High", "flag": "Alert"}]

const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(e => !(["comparison","flag"].includes(e)));
const values = data.map(e => Object.entries(e).filter(([k]) => keys.includes(k)).map(([, v], i ) => {
  if ( i === 0 && Number.isInteger( v ) ) {
    return v.toString();
  }
  return v;
}));
const formattedArray = [keys, ...values];

console.log( formattedArray );
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it turns both columns to a string.  I need the second column to remain an int.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, to proceed in this case you can create a method that receives the `data`, the parameter to use as `key` (x-axis) and the parameter to use as `value` (y-axis) as arguments. Then, you can use a simple [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the input `data` to generate the array of pairs and finally return the desired output. Something like this:

```js
const data = [
  {"id": 1, "cost": 323, "comparison": "High", "flag": "Alert"},
  {"id": 2, "cost": 745, "comparison": "Low", "flag": "Warning"},
  {"id": 3, "cost": 122, "comparison": "Medium", "flag": "Info"}
];

function getHistogram(data, keyParam, valParam)
{
    return [
        [keyParam, valParam],
        ...data.map(o => ["" + o[keyParam], o[valParam]])
    ];
}

console.log(getHistogram(data, "id", "cost"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```